# align the lines

Tags: modeling

I would like to align the lines. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could use project from view in UV editing, if that's what you mean.

Comment: have you tried to move the vertex of the UV in the UV Editor to correct it? Or unwrap again